# Retrieving data from entry

Tags: python, tkinter

When I hit the button in this script I get an error saying

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
 File "grid_layout.py", line 41, in printout
 data = [ { l1.cget("text"): (e1.get(), e2.get()) } for e1,e2,l1 in zip(E1,E2,L1) ]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
from Tkinter import *
import json


root = Tk(  )

E1 = []
E2 = []
E3 = []
L1 = []

Label(root, text="Way Point").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(root, text="x").grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(root, text="y").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(root, text="z").grid(row=0, column=3)

for r in range(1,10):
    l1 = Label(root, text="Number%d" % (r),borderwidth=1).grid(row=r, column=0)
    e1 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=1)
    e2 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=2)
    e3 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=3)
    E1.append(e1)
    E2.append(e2)
    E3.append(e3)
    L1.append(l1)

Label(root, text="zone").grid(row=11, column=0)
Label(root, text="x").grid(row=11, column=1)
Label(root, text="y").grid(row=11, column=2)
Label(root, text="z").grid(row=11, column=3)

for r in range(12,22):
    l2 = Label(root, text="Number%d" % (r-11),borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r, column=0)
    e4 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=1)
    e5 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=2)
    e6 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=3)

def printout():
 # Iterate over the zip of E & L (joined), building the dict using .cget('text') to get
 # the value of the Tkinter label. Add the { 'c':3.0 } to the end of the resulting list
    data = [ { l1.cget("text"): (e1.get(), e2.get()) } for e1,e2,l1 in zip(E1,E2,L1) ]
    print json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=2)

plus = Button(root,  text='Print', command=printout)
plus.grid(row=23, column=1)

root.mainloop(  )
```

Comment: The error message tells you precisely what's wrong -- is there something about the error message you don't understand? It's telling you that `e1` is None, so all you need to do is find the place where you think you're defining it and check whether the code is doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
e1 = Entry(root, width=10).grid(row=r, column=1)
```

In this case this does the same as:

```
e1 = Entry(root, width=10)
e1 = e1.grid(row=r, column=1)
```

`e1.grid(...)` returns None, so you end up with `e1 = None`. As you use this kind of assignment everywhere, your lists are filled with `None` only, therefore when you later call `... e1.get() ...` on them, you get that error.

Try to separate creating the objects and calling methods on them.

Comment: Your comment that the two are the same is patently false. They are definitely _not_ the same, as you describe later in your answer. I think you need to rephrase the statement "This is the same as:" to be more correct.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Tried to rephrase it a little.